# "I think/thought he is/was kind."

Tags: tense, backshifting

> I think he is kind.
> I think he was kind.

> I thought he is kind.
> I thought he was kind.

Which do you usually use or not?

Answer (score 1):

In general in English you try to keep past and present tense the same in your sentences. So 'think' and 'is' are present tense while 'was' and 'thought' are past.

Your sentences can be understood in various ways, but it's a good general rule to keep tenses to be more easily understandable.

Comment: *try to keep past and present tense the same in your sentences* this doesn't make any sense to me. From *I think he is kind* I understand that the person saying this thinks that *he* is kind in general, but *I think he was kind* feels more like the speaker thinks *he* was being kind at a particular time in past. Not sure if these are correct interpretations though, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in those interpretations, especially for the first two sentences. For the last two however saying "I thought he is kind," is much harder for one to interpret as the speaker in the past is portraying their opinion of the other person presently. Technically it can be allowed in certain circumstances, but for ease of understanding I gave an abbreviated explanation. But indeed you can definitely have the present speaker reminiscing on the past.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Yes, **I thought he is kind** is confusing. But how do we backshift **he is kind** (in general) and **he was kind** (at a particular time) properly? **I thought he was kind** again implies a general kindness, but how do we express kindness perceived at a certain point or an isolated period in the past? **I thought he'd been kind** or **I thought he'd been being kind** doesn't sound natural at all, the latter even sounds ungrammatical.